# How to display rows from 2 different tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different tables..

```
Test1: with 1,2,3,4 as row elements upto 10.
Test2: with a,b,c,d as row elements upto j.
```

I want to display the result through a single query where every even number from the table is followed by the preceding alphabet and the odd numbers and other alphabets are omitted.

Like, for this case, the result would be: `2a, 4c, 6e, 8g, 10i. And 1,3,5,7,9 and b,d,f,h,j` would not be displayed.

I need to do this with a larger table which won't have numbers or alphabets.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May it helpful for you, its in sql server, change it to mysql

```
create table #alpha(alpha varchar(25))
insert #alpha values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f')

create table #Number(digits int)
insert #Number values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)

SELECT CAST(Number.digits as varchar(25))+''+Alphabets.alpha yourResult FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over( order by digits asc) as id,digits from #Number ) Number
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over( order by alpha asc) as id,alpha from #alpha ) Alphabets
ON Alphabets.id+1=Number.id
WHERE Number.digits%2=0

drop table #alpha  
drop table #Number
```

Output:

```
yourResult
2a
4c
6e
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Test1 has a column Number, Test2 has a column Ch:

```
select * from Test1, Test2 where (Number%2=0) and char(95 + Number)=Ch
```

With arbitrary type rows it is not clear as in SQL rows has no any order actually.